# Azure N-Series VM NVIDIA Tesla K80 VM instance GPU/Display Adaptor Issue

Tags: windows-10, gpu, nvidia, tesla, azure-vm

Have a N series Windows 10 VM on Azure with Tesla K80 display adaptor. The VM doesn't seems to use the GPU properly. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Following are the issues with the Azure VM:

**1. Playing GTA is very laggy and you play frame-by-frame.**

**2. The VM doesn't uses the NVIDIA Display Adaptor for the default Generic PnP Monitor.**
[image]

**3. DxDiag is not showing the correct display adaptor information.**
[image]

**4. GPU not showing in Task Manager.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try to switch the GPU to WDDM mode. By default it is in TCC mode.
To do that go to **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI** folder.
Run **nvidia-smi** command-prompt utility to see the current mode and GPU Id.
Then run the command

**nvidia-smi -g {GPU_ID} -dm 0**

or

**nvidia-smi -g {GPU_ID} -fdm 0**

to switch to WDDM.

See more:

[Tesla Compute Cluster (TCC)](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/tesla_compute_cluster.htm)

[Using the GPU on an Azure NVIDIA enabled virtual machine](https://www.peters.com/blog/using-the-gpu-on-an-azure-nvidia-enabled-virtual-machine/)

Comment: Thanks. Worked as expected. Got the GPU element in the Task Manager, but the monitor is still connected to Hyper Video.

Comment: You need to be using a NV VM, not NC, i think MS have somehow blocked them for being able to run GPU virtualized desktop apps.